# Chinese characters randomly fail to display correctly

Tags: html, css, internationalization, chinese-locale

I'm working to provide Chinese support for a website. There is one string whose characters sometimes display correctly but sometimes don't (i.e. when I refresh the page sometimes the string is correct, sometimes it isn't).

Below I've posted screenshots of the problem in Chrome. The problem appears in other browsers too though.

Here's what should be [displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5bxA.png). Also, here is the [rendered font information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHGuq.png) when I inspect it

Here is an example of what gets displayed when it goes [wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvXwd.png). Here is the new [rendered font information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTIoc.png)

The big difference seems to be that when it goes wrong, suddenly Tahoma shows up as a font. I should also mention that it isn't always the same characters that get messed up.

Comment: Have you tried to use any Chinese fonts? "MS PGothic" is a Japanese font with proportional latin in the gothic (sans serif) style. @user987123